# Do we have a "leaving job" type tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions related to leaving your current job, do we have a good tag for these?

We have [job-change](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-change) but I'm not sure this is appropriate as there are specific things related to leaving a job which don't necessarily match the tag there.

Comment: Does [tag:resignation] not work?

Comment: @Rarity I guess I don't see why not (unless of course you are killed in a tragic accident rather than resigning...) - guess I didn't see that one

Answer (score 5):

[resignation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resignation) seems to work.

Comment: If you can think of other terms, add them and propose a synonym.  It always sucks having tags people can't think of.

Comment: @NickC I wasn't sure what to do at all not sure even on this. Maybe I'll add [tag:leaving-job] as a synonym

Comment: leaving-job and quitting maybe. Possibly termination but perhaps that should be more for the management side not the side of the employee who's leaving?

Comment: We also have some on specific aspects of leaving a job - like knowledge-transfer is in there.